# Emacs Python-mode format-message error

Tags: python

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and Emacs 24. but recently when i open a Python source file in Emacs or create a new one, i get an error:

> symbol's function definition is void: format-message

The file is opened as a Fundamental.

Comment: If the file is opening in fundamental mode, then it's _not_ opening in python-mode. Do you have something in your init file (`init.el` / `.emacs.d` / etc) like: `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py$" . python-mode))` ?

Comment: okay i just fixed the problem deleting the python.el file it was loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question in some IRC group's and came up with an answer...
it seemed that elpa Python.el package, tries to load a file that is not python and is C++...

I just had to delete the file and it worked again.

Comment: This is not correct.  The issue is that you have installed python.el from GNU ELPA which is the version made for Emacs 25.  Using this version in Emacs 24 will give you an error as it's using Emacs 25 functionality.  As Emacs 24 contains an older version of python.el that works just fine, it's sufficient to delete the user-installed version to solve this problem.